# how to access a .js file from a .jsp file, residing in a different webapplication folder

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat

I have following situation:
WebProject Structure:

```
- WebContent (Folder)
    - js (Folder)
        myfunctions.js (Javascript File)
    - jsps (folder)
        myjsp.jsp (JSP-File)
```

How do reference the javascriptfile (myfunctions.js) in my Java Server Page (myjsp.jsp) to be included ? Following doesn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/myfunctions.js"></script>
```

What I have done so far :

I added a Servlet Mapping in **web.xml** to access static contents in Tomcat

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I can Access the file by direct requesting it:

```
http://localhost:8080/mycontextroot/js/myfunctions.js
```

When referencing with absolute path in my jsp , it is also working, but this is not best practice:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/mycontextroot/js/myfunctions.js"></script>
```

Any help ? I also would like to prevent using reference location path with ../../../

Comment: In the headline you wrote WEB-INF, in the text WebContent. So which on is it? The WEB-INF directory is a subdirectory  of webContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using EL, you'd go

```
<script ... src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/myfunctions.js">
</script>
```

With plain JSP

```
<script ... src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/myfunctions.js" >
</script>
```

Seeing @Stefan's comment, I'm assuming that the JS file is *not* under WEB-INF, as it wouldn't be available to the browser from there. I'll correct the question title accordingly, to match your question's description.